# Meteor and typescript, definition not imported?

Tags: meteor, typescript-typings

I do use [meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) to perform some before.update action as follows:

```
MyCollection.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier : Mongo.Modifier, options) {
    modifier.$set.code = Utils.uppercase(modifier.$set.code);
    modifier.$set.name = Utils.uppercaseFirst(modifier.$set.name);
```

When running the server I obtain a:

```
Property '$set' does not exist on type 'Modifier'.
```

Note that this error is also visible while editing with Atom.

**However, at run time, this works and the code and name are updated as wanted. Any hint of what could be wrong ?**

I was not able to identify the issue. I suppose this could be typings issue, however my typings.json does correctly includes     "typings/meteor/index.d.ts" that contains the definition of Modifier as an object.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's be clear about one thing: type errors in typescript compilation are just for you -- **the code will be converted to JS despite having errors in it**. Your collection is updated, because meteor runs JS, not the typescript you wrote.

What the Atom and compiler are complaining about is a bad definition of `Mongo.Modifier` type. I assume you are using the declarations file from `typings`, which defines `Mongo` as:

```
declare namespace Mongo {
    interface Selector {
      [key: string]:any;
    }
    interface Selector extends Object {}
    interface Modifier {}
    interface SortSpecifier {}
    interface FieldSpecifier {
      [id: string]: Number;
    }
}
```

Quick solution: drop the `Mongo.Modifier` type from your function, the error will go away and you are not getting anything from that anyways.

Better solution: update the file according to MongoDB docs and subimt a pull request :)